# Create new column by counting distinct values in another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have a dataframe such as:

```
COL1_1 COL1_3            COL2
Chr1_0 Canis_lupus       A
Chr1_0 Canis_lupus       A
Chr1_0 Canis_lupus       B
Chr1_0 Canis_lupus       B
Chr1_0 Canis_lupus       B
Chr1_0 Felis_cattus      B
Chr1_0 Felis_cattus      B
Chr2_0 Felis_cattus      A
Chr2_0 Felis_cattus      B
Chr2_1 Felis_cattus      C
Chr2_1 Felis_cattus      D
Chr2_1 Felis_cattus      E
```

and the idea is within each `COL1_1` and `COL1_3`  count the number of distinct `COL2`.

ex : for `Chr1_0` and `Canis_lupus` there are 2 distinct `COL2` (A and B), so I put 2 into the new  `COL3`.

if there is only one value, I put a 0.

here I should then get

```
COL1_1 COL1_3            COL2  COL3
Chr1_0 Canis_lupus       A     2
Chr1_0 Canis_lupus       A     2
Chr1_0 Canis_lupus       B     2
Chr1_0 Canis_lupus       B     2
Chr1_0 Canis_lupus       B     2
Chr1_0 Felis_cattus      B     0
Chr1_0 Felis_cattus      B     0
Chr2_0 Felis_cattus      A     2
Chr2_0 Felis_cattus      B     2
Chr2_1 Felis_cattus      C     3
Chr2_1 Felis_cattus      D     3
Chr2_1 Felis_cattus      E     3
```

maybe an idea would be to groupby (COL1_1`and`COL1_3`) and count number of distinct COL2 values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) and [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) for replace `1` to `0`:

```
df['COL3'] = (df.groupby(['COL1_1', 'COL1_3']).COL2.transform('nunique')
                .mask(lambda x: x == 1, 0))
```

Or use `replace`:

```
df['COL3'] = df.groupby(['COL1_1', 'COL1_3']).COL2.transform('nunique').replace({1:0})
```

---

```
print (df)
    COL1_1        COL1_3 COL2  COL3
0   Chr1_0   Canis_lupus    A     2
1   Chr1_0   Canis_lupus    A     2
2   Chr1_0   Canis_lupus    B     2
3   Chr1_0   Canis_lupus    B     2
4   Chr1_0   Canis_lupus    B     2
5   Chr1_0  Felis_cattus    B     0
6   Chr1_0  Felis_cattus    B     0
7   Chr2_0  Felis_cattus    A     2
8   Chr2_0  Felis_cattus    B     2
9   Chr2_1  Felis_cattus    C     3
10  Chr2_1  Felis_cattus    D     3
11  Chr2_1  Felis_cattus    E     3
```